# why is wrong with 'if [ $# > 0 ] ; then'?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sh

why does it still produce output in the third command?

```
$cat sh.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo $#
if [ $# > 0 ] ; then
    base=`basename $1 .c`
    echo $base
fi
$ sh sh.sh a.c
1
a
$ sh sh.sh
0
.c
```

I use this file:/usr/share/doc/opencv-doc/examples/c/build_all.sh to build the c examples for opencv packages,but failed with similar errors.

Comment: If your shebang says `#!/bin/sh` you're not really using Bash. If you want to use `>` and double parentheses as codaddict mentions, then you need `#!/bin/bash`. Then you can do `if (( $# > ))`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `-gt` in place of `>`.

You can use `>` if you are using [double parenthesis construct](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dblparens.html).

Comment: Thanks,so this is a bug in opencv-doc package.At least the first line should be changed to `#!/bin/bash` or **>** to **-gt**.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `-gt`(Greater than) in your condition, not `>`. Look at `man test` for more information.

```
if [ $# -gt 0 ] ; then
    base=`basename $1 .c`
    echo $base
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember that `[` *is* a command. `/usr/bin/[` , to be exact. It is linked to the command `/usr/bin/test`

So, `[ $# > 0` is identical to `test $# > 0`, i.e., redirect `test $#`'s output to the `0` file.

If you're using **`bash`** ... now that's a different story altogether :-)

Comment: `[` is a builtin in several shells in addition to Bash, but you're correct that it is a *command*. `/usr/bin/[` (and `/usr/bin/test`) exists mostly for backwards compatibility for shells that don't include it. It can also be used when you're not really using a shell, for example in the `-exec` clause of a `find` command.